# PHP curl возвращает содержимое типа text/html

Tags: php, post, curl

Я пытаюсь отправить POST запрос, используя PHP curl, в заголовке указываю, что content type = application/json, но результат всё равно остаётся text/html.  В postman, ответ приходит правильно с типом содержимого application/json. Как решить эту проблему?

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.business.kazanexpress.ru/api/oauth/token";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Basic token",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Connection: Keep-Alive"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{"username": "username", "password": "password!", "grant_type": "password"}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Ответ через PHP

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ через Postman
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, стоит добавить заголовок
чтобы ответ точно был в json
"Accept": "application/json"

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).